# Handling touch events on overlapping buttons

Tags: android, user-interface, button

I wonder if someone can help. I have overlapping buttons on my Android UI (see image below). Although the layout may look messy, it is actually exactly what I need. The buttons actually represent real objects, so they need to be in their actual positions (and also displayed to their actual sizes).

The trouble is that some of the buttons overlap one another. In some cases, the smaller buttons are covered completely by larger ones and are only visible because the larger ones are slightly translucent. The question is: how can I get button clicks from the buttons which are underneath others? I have looked at passing the click event on if the touch wasn't near the centre of a button, but I can't see a way of doing this. For the puposes of experimentation, I have also disabled some of the larger buttons to see if the smaller ones then receive the event, but that doesn't happen. Is there a way of doing this? I don't want the user to have to hide the large buttons from the display in order to get to the smaller ones; that would be really tedious. I would be really grateful for some help with this! [Image showing part of screen with overlapping buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFhNh.jpg)

Comment: How will the user know what button he is clicking?

Comment: The button changes colour when it's been clicked.

Comment: If you have two overlapping buttons which will change color when the user clicks on both of them?

Comment: Well, that's the thing, really: the user CAN'T click on both of them. The click event always relates to the button in the foreground, so the one that is obscured can't be clicked. I would like to be able to click on either, for example by having a smaller touch-sensitive area which is just around the centre of the button. I don't want the button to be clicked when any part of the background drawable is touched, but I can't see a way of doing that.